# Where is Tracker Smurf?

Tags: smurfs-village

I bought his cauldron two weeks ago, and he still hasn't shown up - every time I tap the cauldron it just tells me that he is in the forest looking for ingredients.  It mentioned that I need an Internet connection but since my phone is usually on Wifi and I have unlimited data otherwise that should not be a problem.

Where is Tracker Smurf?

Comment: Reports seem to indicate that this is a bug - you might try closing the app completely (ie, even from the multitask bar, or try completely rebooting your device) and restarting it.  Sometimes the game doesn't recognize the internet connection even though it is present.